# Extract value from AWS Cloudwatch logstream using CDK

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I have a log stream as below in Cloudwatch and I am trying to extract value from the log

```
START RequestId: 5ee6cb52-06d3-4552-858e-fd76c46e0e08 Version: $LATEST

[INFO]  2020-07-02T12:50:11.142Z    5ee6cb52-06d3-4552-858e-fd76c46e0e08    { KPI:{ AR:5 } }

END RequestId: 5ee6cb52-06d3-4552-858e-fd76c46e0e08
```

I am trying write a Metricfilter in AWS CDK to pull out value 5 from the log. The code for the filter as below

```
const METRIC_AR_JSON_PATTERN = '$.KPI.AR'    
new MetricFilter(this, 'DemoMetricFilter', {
                metricName: METRIC_NAME,
                metricNamespace: METRIC_NAMESPACE,
                logGroup: logGroup,
                filterPattern: FilterPattern.numberValue(METRIC_AR_JSON_PATTERN, '==', 5),
                metricValue: '5'
            })
```

The MetricFilter has been successfully created but the log data has not been pulled. Please advice on what changes I need to do in FilterPattern

Answer (score 0):

The equality operator is `=` not `==` in the metric filter : [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) and [cdk-docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-logs-readme.html).

```
const METRIC_AR_JSON_PATTERN = '$.KPI.AR'    
new MetricFilter(this, 'DemoMetricFilter', {
                metricName: METRIC_NAME,
                metricNamespace: METRIC_NAMESPACE,
                logGroup: logGroup,
                filterPattern: FilterPattern.numberValue(METRIC_AR_JSON_PATTERN, '=', 5),
                metricValue: '5'
            })
```